# Angular docker-compose not reflecting changes when using nginx

Tags: angular, docker

when I am using Docker-compose using nginx, I am not able to see realtime changes in my running container.

**My docker file:**

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build -- --prod

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html/

COPY --from=builder /app/nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY ./replace_api_url.sh /tmp
CMD ["sh", "/tmp/replace_api_url.sh"]
```

**My docker-compose file:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFtQf.png)

Comment: That Dockerfile is not well-suited for hot reload. You're going to need to build the image and restart the container every time you make a change.

Comment: I am using docker-compose for real time changes. I have attached screenshot of my docker-compose file